# Python Function Not Changing Variable

Tags: python, pygame

I am a c++ programmer and am learning pygame so I am very new to python. I noticed this behavior of functions and don't know what to do about it:

let's say we have a global variable:

```
x = 10
```

Now let's say we have a function that changes the value of x:

```
def foo():
    x = 100
```

Now, inside my main pygame loop, if I call foo(), the variable x is still 10 after the function call. How is this happening???

Comment: You need `global x` in the function.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python

Comment: `x = 100` simply creates a variable local to `foo`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function local scope value of x is changed. The x defined outside the function has global scope. To change global value try `global var_name` statement inside function before updating value

```
def foo():
  global x
  x = 100
```

Comment: no, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, you implicitly create another variable x, and then set it to 100. To change the global variable try this:

```
 def foo(): 
              global x
              x = 100
```